# Checking if something is empty

Tags: c#

I am currently checking if comboboxes and numericupdowns are empty but i am doing it with If statement.

Can you tell me if there is any other faster way of doing it?

Here is current code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            if(comboBox2.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                if(numericUpDown1.Value != 0)
                {
                    if(numericUpDown2.Value != 0)
                    {
                        if(numericUpDown3.Value != 0)
                        {
                            if(numericUpDown4.Value != 0)
                            {
                                string domacin = "" + comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                                int D_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                                int D_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
                                int D_ukupnoKoseva = D_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme + D_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme;
                                int D_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
                                int D_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
                                int D_ukupnoPrimljenihKoseva = D_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme + D_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme;

                                string gost = "" + comboBox2.GetItemText(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
                                int G_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
                                int G_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
                                int G_ukupnoKoseva = G_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme + G_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme;
                                int G_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                                int G_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
                                int G_ukupnoPrimljenihKoseva = G_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme + G_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme;

                                int rezultat;
                                Functions.odrediPobednika(out rezultat, D_ukupnoKoseva, G_ukupnoKoseva);

                                //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\arist\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\NBA\NBA\NBA.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Faster to type: yes. Faster to execute: no.

Comment: You can use only one If statement

Comment: `if (a) { if (b) { if (c) { ... } } }` --> `if (a && b && c) { ... }`.

Comment: Will you need to do this several times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use following fail-fast-validation approach with meaningful messages:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (comboBox1.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meaningful message, user should know what he has done wrong", "Invalid xyz");
        return;
    }
    else if (comboBox2.SelectedItem == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meaningful message, user should know what he has done wrong", "Invalid xyz");
        return;
    }
    else if (numericUpDown1.Value == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meaningful message, user should know what he has done wrong", "Invalid xyz");
        return;
    }
    else if (numericUpDown2.Value == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meaningful message, user should know what he has done wrong", "Invalid xyz");
        return;
    }
    else if (numericUpDown3.Value == 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Meaningful message, user should know what he has done wrong", "Invalid xyz");
        return;
    }

    // insert code
}
```

It's neither shorter nor more efficient, but it's easy to read, to debug and most important: the user knows what went wrong. You should also use meaningful control-names.

Of course you could also use one `if` and concat all conditions with `&&`, but i'd prefer my first approach for the reasons mentioned above.

```
bool valid = comboBox1.SelectedItem != null 
          && comboBox2.SelectedItem != null 
          && numericUpDown1.Value != 0 
          && numericUpDown2.Value != 0 
          && numericUpDown3.Value != 0 
          && numericUpDown4.Value != 0;
if(valid){
    //Code
}
```

Comment: Typo: You check for `numericUpDown1's value == 0` 3 times

Comment: That's why I said typo :)

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that springs to mind is to use one if statement

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null && comboBox2.SelectedItem != null && numericUpDown1.Value != 0 && numericUpDown2.Value != 0 && numericUpDown3.Value != 0 && numericUpDown4.Value != 0)
{
    //Code
}
```

This can also be put onto multiple lines for readability

```
if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null &&
 comboBox2.SelectedItem != null &&
 numericUpDown1.Value != 0 &&
 numericUpDown2.Value != 0 &&
 numericUpDown3.Value != 0 &&
 numericUpDown4.Value != 0)
{
    //Code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to optimize there in reference to execution times etc. But the code could be made a bit neater, a start could be something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(comboBox1.SelectedItem != null &&
           comboBox2.SelectedItem != null &&
           numericUpDown1.Value != 0 &&
           numericUpDown2.Value != 0 &&
           numericUpDown3.Value != 0 &&
           numericUpDown4.Value != 0)
           {
              string domacin = comboBox1.GetItemText(comboBox1.SelectedItem);
                                int D_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                                int D_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
                                int D_ukupnoKoseva = D_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme + D_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme;
                                int D_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
                                int D_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
                                int D_ukupnoPrimljenihKoseva = D_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme + D_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme;

                                string gost = comboBox2.GetItemText(comboBox2.SelectedItem);
                                int G_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown2.Value;
                                int G_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown4.Value;
                                int G_ukupnoKoseva = G_kosevaDrugoPoluvreme + G_kosevaPrvoPoluvreme;
                                int G_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
                                int G_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme = (int)numericUpDown3.Value;
                                int G_ukupnoPrimljenihKoseva = G_primljenihKosevaDrugoPoluvreme + G_primljenihKosevaPrvoPoluvreme;

                                int rezultat;
                                Functions.odrediPobednika(out rezultat, D_ukupnoKoseva, G_ukupnoKoseva);

                                //SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\arist\Documents\VisualStudio2015\Projects\NBA\NBA\NBA.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
                                //SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("", con);
    }
}
```